# aws describe-volumes behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

My filter for aws describe-volumes is not working. Not sure what is going wrong. All the different possible values for attachment.status returns no volumes. The volume is actually attached fine. Here is the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html

```
root@84837b512326:/app# aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters 
Name=attachment.status,Values=detaching --volume-ids vol-0e244fb776d97de63 
{
     "Volumes": []    
}
root@84837b512326:/app# aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.status,Values=detached --volume-ids vol-0e244fb776d97de63 
{
    "Volumes": []
}
root@84837b512326:/app# aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.status,Values=attached --volume-ids vol-0e244fb776d97de63 
{
    "Volumes": []
}
root@84837b512326:/app# aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=attachment.status,Values=attaching --volume-ids vol-0e244fb776d97de63 

{
    "Volumes": []
}
root@84837b512326:/app# aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids vol-0e244fb776d97de63 
{
    "Volumes": [
    {
        "AvailabilityZone": "us-west-2b", 
        "Attachments": [
            {
                "AttachTime": "2017-07-10T23:18:36.000Z", 
                "InstanceId": "i-07ad32a6d30cb3081", 
                "VolumeId": "vol-0e244fb776d97de63", 
                "State": "busy", 
                "DeleteOnTermination": false, 
                "Device": "/dev/sdb"
            }
        ], 
        "Encrypted": false, 
        "VolumeType": "gp2", 
        "VolumeId": "vol-0e244fb776d97de63", 
        "State": "in-use", 
        "Iops": 100, 
        "SnapshotId": "", 
        "CreateTime": "2017-07-10T20:15:25.154Z", 
        "Size": 5
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Documentation bug? Does a filter of Name=attachment.status,Values=busy work?

Comment: Either @jarmod is onto something, or `busy` is a state that can't be queried.  A "busy" volume sounds like it could be in an unhappy state transition or possibly attached to a failed instance or an instance that isn't responding to the last state state transition request... which seems incompatible with the observation that the volume is fine.

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case. 'Busy' seems to be a bad state. Other states can be queried fine it seems. After leaving for a few hours, the volume is detached and things work as predicted.

Answer (score 0):

You're misusing the `--filters` argument.

It takes arguments of the form `--filter Name="instance-id",Values="i-1234abcd"`; note the quotes for string passing.